# How to specify leverage and portion-of-account-balance in strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried to extract it from [the manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#leverage) but it is not clear to me, could not identify which argument of `strategy.entry()` is the leverage.

```
strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, when, alert_message) → void
```

For the balance portion amount, perhaps I can always calculate it so it can be handled. `strategy.position_size`? **Is this the right approach?** And the right function?

And **How to specify leverage and portion-of-account-balance in strategy('s code)?**

*I see that in the strategy settings panel, the amount can specified but what part of the code does this? O' the contrary, I don't see a leverage on this panel.*

[image: Strategy Settings Panel]

Here's Currency.com's Order Panel I established my approach on.

[image: Currency.com's Order Panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the first line where you pick indicator/strategy/library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQua6.png)

the * 5 is one thing you can do for leverage or you can adjust the qty of your order in your strategy.entry call.. but really leverage has a lot of weird fees and margin requirements plus like a safety/risk fee you can find them on your exchanges fee information..

Comment: Oh, it's cool! And how to alter it for the case when the positions' size is based on not qty but equity-percentage? (As we can specify it in the Strategy Settings Panel but I don't find the variable in the code of the Strategy though.)

I have just posted another question in this topic. Would you please look into it when you have time, and include this detail into the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115590/how-to-set-up-a-strategy-properly-v5 

I "can't not" thank it to you. :)