# What is the X Axis in the Strategy Test Result Chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

Timeframe is 1H, runtime since ~ June 2020, ETHUSD. (This is my pre-first try to write a basic but functional strategy and run its test.)

Trying a calculation, I can't take out this runtime period from that >6000 on the X Axis. If it was hours than it should have been ~15000…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the number of trades.

You have 6069 closed trades and the x-axis ends around that number.

Comment: Every single answer you give helps so much. Would you please check on this question? I updated it to be more clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106589/how-to-specify-leverage-and-portion-of-account-balance-in-strategy

Comment: Leverage is not my thing unfortunately :)